# Shell script that SSH's into another machine, runs another script, 2nd script asks for user input

Tags: shell, ssh, nested

```
ssh -t -t me@myothermachine.ca<<EOF
cd ../../path/to/script/directory/
sh copyfiles.sh
cd ../../copied/directory
sh renamer.sh
exit
EOF
```

Hi guys,

The script above is what I'm working with.  copyfiles.sh has a 'read' asking for the year and then the month of the files that I'd like to copy.  The files it will be copying has the year and month in the title so it looks at the title of the file and finds all the files for that year and month the user enters.  It's probably easier for you to just have a look at the code to see what it's doing actually.  Here it is.

```
#get the year and the month from the user
echo "Please enter the year"
read year
echo "Please enter the month"
read month

files=`find . -name "*$year*$month*.txt"`

for file in $files; do
    cp $file /the/copy/to/directory
done
```

The issue I get is that I enter "2014" when it asks, then just hangs.

It logs into my other machine, shows the the middle 5 lines of code from my initial script, then starts reading them as commands.  It cd's properly, then gets to the sh copyfiles.sh script, It asks for the year, I enter the year, and it hangs.

Is user input like this with shell script not doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  If you have the source to `copyfiles.sh`, you should modify it so that you can pass the required input as arguments to `copyfiles.sh`.  Then, your ssh session can execute it for you, e.g.

```
ssh -t -t me@myothermachine.ca<<EOF
    cd ../../path/to/script/directory/
    sh copyfiles.sh --year 2014 --month june
    cd ../../copied/directory
    sh renamer.sh
    exit
EOF
```